# react-native-keychain does not persist data on android

Tags: react-native, react-native-keychain

I am using `react-native-keychain` for storing data.
In `ios` it is working fine even you uninstall and re-install the app.
But on `android` it is returning `false`

```
export const setCredentials = async ({
  username,
  password,
}: {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}) => {
  try {
    const server = await DeviceInfo.getBundleId();
    return await setInternetCredentials(server, username, password, {
      storage: STORAGE_TYPE.AES,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
};
```

I tried to change the `AES` into `FB` but it is crashing.

Any idea about this?

Thanks!